# c# screen capture virtual desktop

Tags: c#, desktop, virtual, screen, capture

I've found a way to create virtual desktops with c#.  Now I was wondering if we can take a screenshot of a particular desktop and if so how ?

Thanks in advance

Blizz

Answer (score 1):

HAve you tried the `CopyFromScreen` method in the GFX Object

```
        Graphics g = new Graphics();
        g.CopyFromScreen(  ....params.... )
```

Comment: I assume with virtual desktop Blizz means a dektop created with CreateDesktop. CopyFromScreen won't work across desktops.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but the first thing I'd try is:

- create a new thread
- switch the thread to the new desktop by calling SetThreadDesktop
- take a screen shot
- switch thread back

might just work.