# How do I find the position / location of a window given a hWnd without NativeMethods?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, watin, screenshot

I'm currently working with WatiN, and finding it to be a great web browsing automation tool.  However, as of the last release, it's screen capturing functionality seems to be lacking.  I've come up with a workable solution for capturing screenshots from the screen (independently generating code similar to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922546/c-screen-capture-virtual-desktop)) in addition to some [code by Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pwcs/ReadingPixelsFromTheScreen.html).  Unfortunately, there is a missing component: *Where is the actual window*?

WatiN conveniently provides the browser's `hWnd` to you, so we can (with this simplified example) get set to copy an image from the screen, like so:

```
// browser is either an WatiN.Core.IE or a WatiN.Core.FireFox...
IntPtr hWnd = browser.hWnd;
string filename = "my_file.bmp";
using (Graphics browser = Graphics.FromHwnd(browser.hWnd) )
using (Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap((int)browser.VisibleClipBounds.Width,
                                      (int)browser.VisibleClipBounds.Height,
                                      browser))
using (Graphics screenGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
{
    int hWndX = 0; // Upper left of graphics?  Nope, 
    int hWndY = 0; // this is upper left of the entire desktop!

    screenGraphics.CopyFromScreen(hWndX, hWndY, 0, 0, 
                          new Size((int)browser.VisibileClipBounds.Width,
                                   (int)browser.VisibileClipBounds.Height));
    screenshot.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Success!  We get screenshots, but there's that problem: `hWndX` and `hWndY` always point to the upper left most corner of the screen, not the location of the window we want to copy from.

I then looked into `Control.FromHandle`, however this seems to only work with forms you created; this method returns a null pointer if you pass the `hWnd` into it.

Then, further reading lead me to switch my search criteria...I had been searching for 'location of window' when most people really want the 'position' of the window.  This lead to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364440/how-to-get-and-set-window-position-of-another-application-in-c) that talked about this, but their answer was to use native methods.

So, **Is there a native C# way of finding the position of a window, only given the hWnd (preferably with only .NET 2.0 era libraries)?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I just went through this on a project and was unable to find any managed C# way.

To add to Reed's answer the P/Invoke code is:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
 private struct RECT
 {
     public int Left;
     public int Top;
     public int Right;
     public int Bottom;
  }
```

Call it as:

```
  RECT rct = new RECT();
  GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rct);
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that will do it.

Comment: Hi Robert,

Could you post your complete solution? I would love to add screencapture functionality for firefox and other browsers (chrome).

Thanks in advance!
Jeroen (lead dev WatiN)

Comment: And the complete solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434524/how-do-i-find-the-position-location-of-a-window-given-a-hwnd-without-nativemeth/1461322#1461322

Answer (score 6):

No - if you didn't create the form, you have to P/Invoke [GetWindowRect](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowRect.html).  I don't believe there is a managed equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is as others have stated, probably "No, you cannot take a screenshot of a random window from an hwnd without native methods.".  Couple of caveats before I show it:

**Forewarning:**

For anyone who wants to use this code, note that the size given from the VisibleClipBounds is only *inside* the window, and does *not* include the border or title bar.  It's the drawable area.  If you had that, you might be able to do this without p/invoke.

(If you could calculate the border of the browser window, you could use the VisibleClipBounds.  If you wanted, you could use the [`SystemInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation_properties.aspx) object to get important info like [`Border3DSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.border3dsize.aspx), or you could try to calculate it by creating a dummy form and [deriving the border and title bar height from that](http://ivision.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/title-bar-height-and-form-border-width-of-net-form/), but that all sounds like the black magic that bugs are made of.)

This is equivalent to Ctrl+Printscreen of the window.  This also does not do the niceties that the WatiN screenshot capability does, such as scroll the browser and take an image of the whole page.  This is suitable for my project, but may not be for yours.

**Enhancements:**

This could be changed to be an extension method if you're in .NET 3 and up-land, and an option for the image type could be added pretty easily (I default to `ImageFormat.Bmp` for this example).

**Code:**

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Screenshot
{
    class NativeMethods
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(VS.85).aspx
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);

        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5ch4fda(VS.80).aspx
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Takes a screenshot of the browser.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="b">The browser object.</param>
    /// <param name="filename">The path to store the file.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool SaveScreenshot(Browser b, string filename)
    {
        bool success = false;
        IntPtr hWnd = b.hWnd;
        NativeMethods.RECT rect = new NativeMethods.RECT();
        if (NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rect))
        {
            Size size = new Size(rect.Right - rect.Left,
                                 rect.Bottom - rect.Top);
            // Get information about the screen
            using (Graphics browserGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(hWnd))
            // apply that info to a bitmap...
            using (Bitmap screenshot = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height, 
                                                  browserGraphics))
            // and create an Graphics to manipulate that bitmap.
            using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot))
            {
                int hWndX = rect.Left;
                int hWndY = rect.Top;
                imageGraphics.CopyFromScreen(hWndX, hWndY, 0, 0, size);
                screenshot.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                success = true;
            }
        }
        // otherwise, fails.
        return success;
    }   
}
```